# Shortest path algorithm

Tags: c++

gd morning . .. 
i made a program to solve dijkstra shortest algorithm . . 
code is as below :-

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define INFINITY 2000
#define MAXNODES 4
#define MEMBER 1
#define NONMEMBER 0
    }
```

and i give input string as 0 
2
3
7
2
0
6
0
3
6
0
1
7
0
1
0

but when i choose starting and final node then it give wrong output . . i don't know where it is . . plz help . .

Comment: Did you debug your code?

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious error is that in C++ you count arrays from **zero**.

So

```
int weight[MAXNODES][MAXNODES],precede[MAXNODES],pd;
cout<<"Enter Weight Matrix :- \n ";
for(i=1;i<=MAXNODES;i++)
{
    for(j=1;j<=MAXNODES;j++)
    {
        cout<<"["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"] :- ";
        cin>>weight[i][j];
    }
}
```

should be

```
int weight[MAXNODES][MAXNODES],precede[MAXNODES],pd;
cout<<"Enter Weight Matrix :- \n ";
for(i=0;i<MAXNODES;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<MAXNODES;j++)
    {
        cout<<"["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"] :- ";
        cin>>weight[i][j];
    }
}
```

Same for all your other loops.